# Redirect PHP url with key values

Tags: php, apache, redirect

I am trying to redirect a url with php key values to a different domain.

The site is being deprecated so I tried a simple redirect by hard coding the URL but could not get that to succeed.

I have also tried using `RewriteCond` using `QUERY_STRING` and `RewriteRule`.  I found success using only 1 key value here but when I tried using multiple key values, it does not pick up the second key and causes the redirect to fail.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (|&)key1=value1($|&)

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (|&)key2=value2($|&)

RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/new/path [L,R=301]
```

Expected result: `example1.com/sample.php?key1=value1&key2=value2`  --> `example2.com/new/path`

Comment: You could also solve this in PHP as explained in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a single `RewriteCond` to check your querystring before redirecting to the new site .

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)key1=value1&key2=value=2($|&) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?sample\.php$ https://www.example.com/new/path?  [L,R=301]
```

The empty question mark `?` at the end of the destination path is important as it discards the old querystring from new url otherwise if it removed then your new url will look something like `example.com/new/path?key1=value1&key2=value2` .

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this new rule.

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)key1=value1&key2=value2($|&) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/app/path? [L,R=301] . I have the same issue as before where if I have a second key value, it redirects back to https://www.example.com/key1.  With only 1, it redirects to the exact page I want.  Is the (.*) causing this issue?

Comment: @KevinBraga Try clearing your browser cache. Also if there are other similar rules then try  removing them just to see if that solves it.